# Connect PySerial to Bluetooth COM port via BlueSoleil on Windows 7

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with a Bluetooth COM port, via Python on a Windows 7 machine. Since this Computer has no built-in Bluetooth, I use a USB stick which works with BlueSoleil (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueSoleil).

My problem seems to be, that BlueSoleil, after a successfull pairing to a COM port, Python cannot open it (access denied). When I define a serial port with PySerial and try to write to it without opening it explicitly, I have no success and a few minutes later the computer crashes with a bluescreen.

When using a terminal (Kitty), I can read and write from and to the port.

My suspicion is, that PySerial tries to 'block' the port, which conflicts with BlueSoleil, but I am not sure.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems, that the Problem is bad drivers of the no-name Bluetooth Dongle under Win 7.
I am now using a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and after installing the needed Packages and loading the needed modules, I have no Problems to connect my Bluetooth device to a serial port.